# $\sin(t)$ is not an open mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading about the Open Mapping Theorem from Kreyzig's Introductory Functional Analysis. I have hard time understanding an example which he introduces of a mapping that is not open. He writes that the mappping $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(t)=\sin(t)$ maps $(0,2\pi)$ onto $[-1,1]$ and thus the mapping is not open, but why not onto $(-1,1)$ instead?

Comment: what are $\sin(\pi/2)$ and $\sin(3\pi/2)$?

Answer (score 4):

$f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ and $f(\frac{3\pi}{2})=-1$, thus

$$1,-1 \in f((0,2 \pi))$$